# How to make Corner Ribbon in PDF using TCPDF library

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library to generate pdf documents in my project. problem is that I want to make corner ribbon in pdf (as shown in the picture) but failed to do that, examples that are available in web that make it using css, they do not work for me in pdf.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6ITJ.png)

Comment: Use absolute position rule.

Answer (score 0):

Create an transparent image like this [image: transparent image for ribbon] as same as your document width and try [this way](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_051/) or [this way](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_042/). I prefer the second one.

Previously I was solved slimier type of problem for a watermark. Hope It will work for you. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you must set the coord x,y like this

```
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$col1 = "p.p Inmobiliaria xxxxxxxx \n Roxxxxx \n xxxx: xxxxxxx";
$col2 = "" . $nombre . " \n Rut: " . $rut . " \n Comprador";
$pdf->Image('firma.png', $x + 10, $y - 40, 0, 0);

$pdf->MultiCell(80, 6, $col1, 0, 1);

$pdf->SetXY($x + 120, $y);
```